# JSch - Check locked account error

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

On linux machine, when account is locked due to max failed login attempt, and while trying to login using ssh it gives below message.

```
Account locked due to 6 failed logins
Password:
Account locked due to 7 failed logins
Password:
```

However while doing ssh using JSch, it gives "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail" exception.

Here, is there any way to catch "Account locked" error?

Thanks in advance,
Vikas